# How To Create Dynamic Hyperlink To Another Sheet In Excel based on the value of another cell

Tags: excel

I have a value in the cell A1 that can be "PERSON, REGISTRATION,CONTRACT"
Then I have to add in the cell A2, an hyperlink to another spreadsheet:
If the value of cell A1 is PERSON  go to spreadsheet2
If the value of cell A1 is REGISTRATION  go to spreadsheet3
If  thevalue of cell A1 isCONTRACT  go to spreadsheet4

How can I do this please ?
Thank You -

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
=HYPERLINK("#'" & CHOOSE(MATCH(A3,{"person";"registration";"contract"},0),
                         "Sheet2","Sheet3","Sheet4" ) & "'!A1", "Go")
```

Edit: some explanation

`MATCH(A3,{"person";"registration";"contract"},0)` -finds the position of the value in A3 in the array of possible values.

Given that position, use CHOOSE() to pick the correct one from the three possible worksheet names to use in the hyperlink address.

The rest is just stringing all of that together to create the link formula.

Comment: Hello, thank you, but could you explain the detail of this ?

Comment: Thank You for your answer -

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
=HYPERLINK("#"& LOOKUP(A1;{"contract";"person";"registration"};{"sheet4!";"sheet2!";"sheet3!"}) &"$a$1";"LINK to " & LOOKUP(A1;{"contract";"person";"registration"};{"sheet4!";"sheet2!";"sheet3!"}))
```

It is important the `lookup_value` must be in alphabetical order and you should be sort the `lookup_vector` accordingly.